# Получение координат при неактивном приложении

Tags: android, gps

Здравствуйте!Можно ли отследить положение человека когда приложение не активно?В фоновом режиме когда оно свёрнуто то можно а вот когда оно закрыто как то можно это сделать?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, можно ли получать координаты gps, то да, можно. Для этого вам в приложении нужно код, работающий с gps оформить в виде сервиса.

Comment: Если можно то опишите по подробнее как это реализуется

Comment: Вот максимально подробное объяснение, на русском да еще и на оф. сайте https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не советовал оформлять данный функционал в сервис. На все фоновые сервисы, начиная с Android 8, накладываются ограничения. Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html).

Если вы используете Google Play Services в вашем приложении, то существует специальный метод [FusedLocationProviderApi#requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, PendingIntent)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), который позволяет подписаться на обновление локейшена и получать данные на BroadcastReceiver.

Например, это можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
final class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
            if (result != null) {
                List<Location> locations = result.getLocations();
                Location lastLocation = result.getLastLocation();
                // start a service or schedule a job to write these locations to a database etc
            }
        }
    }
}

final class LocationManager {
    void requestUpdates() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        FusedLocationProviderApi api = // get this somehow
        api.requestLocationUpdates(client, request, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Почитайте про PendingIntent [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). Преимущество данного метода в том, что он не оказывает нагрузки на систему, т.к. вы не тратите ресурсы на поддержку фонового сервиса. Более того, если вам не столь важно получать локейшены каждые N минут, то вы можете использовать специальную настройку [LocationRequest.html#setMaxWaitTime(long)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setMaxWaitTime(long)). Если установить этот параметр, например, на 30 минут, то LocationReceiver будет вызываться каждые 30 минут, а список локейшен будет содержать все локейшены за прошлые 30 минут с нужным вам интервалом. Таким образом достаточно легко экономить заряд батареи и иметь трек перемещения пользователя.

P.S. Не так давно гугл добавил новый класс для работы с Location API. Блог пост об этом [здесь](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html). Советую взглянуть на него, т.к. он заметно облегчает работу с API и убирает необходимость следить за тем есть ли соединение у GoogleApiClient.

Comment: Не могу понять, откуда взялся **LocationResult**

Comment: @АлександрЗарифулли в этот класс по умолчанию "упаковывается" информация о локейшене. Её предоставляет сам Locations API. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult